# Решения коллизий в мапе

Tags: java, map, коллизии

Коллизия может возникнут при 3 условиях: относительно `hash()`, относительно `hashCode()`, и относительно вычисления индекса. Заключим их в двух ситуациях: например, пусть размер таблицы равен `size`, и есть два объекта: `O1` и `02`.

1. `(hash(O1.hashcode()) % size) == (hash(O2.hashcode()) % size)`, причем `hash(O1.hashcode()) == hash(O2.hashcode())`
2. `(hash(O1.hashcode()) % size) == (hash(O2.hashcode()) % size)`, причем `hash(O1.hashcode()) != hash(O2.hashcode())`

Что будет в ситуации первой?
Что будет в ситуации второй?

Почему делается в первую очередь эта проверка в мапе?

```
if (p.hash == hash && ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Предисловие**

*P.S. Формулировка вопроса оставляет желать лучшего, но раз никто еще не ответил, то я постараюсь додумать и предложить свой вариант ответа.*

Насколько я понимаю речь идет об исходниках `HashMap` из стандартной коллекции java.
Если так, то небольшое превью касательно её устройства (несколько упрощенно) и терминологии:

`HashMap` представляет из себя массив (также называемый buckets), каждым элементом которого (т.е. каждый bucket) является однонаправленным списком (упрощенный аналог `LinkedList`).

При вставке элемента в `HashMap` сначала определяется bucket (индекс массива), куда он должен попасть. Определение bucket'а осуществляется посредством взятия остатка от деления значения `hashCode` (добавляемого элемента) на длину массива (длину buckets).

*P.S. На самом деле, там все несколько сложнее: старшая часть `hashCode` "замешивается" с младшей (`первые_два_байта_hashCode ^ вторые_два_байта_hashCode`), т.к. при определении bucket'а участвует только младшая (в вашем вопросе это соответствует операци `hash(hashCode())`), а от младшей части берутся последние n бит (например, `hash(hashCode()) & 0b1111`), где n-это степень двойки, которая является размером массива.*

---

**Объяснение**

Вначале у вас `if`'ом проверяется факт того, что элементы находятся в одном и том же bucket'е, но это еще не говорит о том, что они равны - просто они были распределены таким образом (см. предисловие).

Если значения `hashCode()` двух элементов не равны, то это гарантировано разные элементы (второй ваш случай).

Если значения `hashCode()` двух элементов равны, то, вероятно (но не факт), что это один и тот же элемент (первый ваш случай). Тем не менее, `hashCode()` выдает значение из множества `int`, которое ограничено 4 байтами (`2^32` уникальных значений), как следствие множество `hashCode()` гарантировано меньше, чем потенциальное количество элементов, которых можно создать в java (оно ограничено лишь доступным размером "кучи" (она же, heap)).

Как следствие, для проверки равенства элементов приходится также сравнивать и сами значения элементов, посредством вызова метода `equals()`.

Можно было бы подумать: "Почему бы сразу не вызвать `equals`, зачем сравнивать hash?"

Сначала сравниваются на равенство hash, т.к. побитово сравнить примитивные 4-байтные `int`'ы куда быстрее, нежели вызвать equals для каждого экземпляра класса, где в общем случае может находиться какой-угодно код сравнения (возможно, написанный крайне неэффективно).
Конечно же, в частном случае (когда в bucket'е ровно один элемент или несколько, но их `hashCode`'ы равны) это может оказаться самую малость менее выгодно.